# More resolution on ListContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a large data set of 1,000,000 3D data points (x,y,z), where z ranges from 0.01 to 0.68, and I'm trying to make a simple, yet informative contour plot like so:

```
ListContourPlot[data,PlotRange -> {{1.0, 1.97}, {1.0, 1.97}, {Min[data[[All,3]]], Max[data[[All,3]]]}},PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True,FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 30, FontFamily -> "Times"}, LabelStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

And the resulting plot looks alright, but the difference in contours is only a measly 0.05! Normally that would be fine, but with 1,000,000 data points, this gives me enormous regions of "this data is inbetween 0.05 and 0.1", which is not very useful for what I'm trying to look at.

I need much more resolution, like at the very least 0.01 inbetween contours (or even less?). Is this possible? I've searched here and Mathematica documentation with no avail. I've also tried ListDensityPlot, however that still isn't what I'm looking for.

Cheers,
Zack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the number of contours with, e.g., `Contours -> 100`. You can also demand that only contours for specific function values of your choice are drawn with, e.g., `Contours -> Range[0.05,0.1,0.01]`.

Comment: This is so nice! They should really specify this in the documentation. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, one _can_ find it: -> go to the doc page of `ListContourPlot` -> go to section "Option" and watch out: Hmm... option "Contours". That seems interesting! -> open the subsection and voilà: plenty of examples! ;)